# Angular 9: how prevent the iOS keyboard of disappearing when changing focus from an input to another inside a form

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, media-queries

Inside my Angular app , i ve this form template :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-input">
        <label>
          <input required>
          <span class="placeholder">Name</span>
          <button class="reset_input border-0 bg-transparent p-0 m-0"><i class="icon-delete"></i>
          </button>

        </label>
        <span class="error "><span class="alert-icon icon-error-severe" aria-hidden="true"></span>Caractère invalide</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-input">
        <label>
          <input required>
          <span class="placeholder">Surname</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-input">
        <label>
          <input required>
          <span class="placeholder">CIN</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-input">
        <label>
          <input required>
          <span class="placeholder">Ville</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-input">
        <label>
          <input required>
          <span class="placeholder">Departement</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

And i'm applying this css :

```
.bloc_advanced_search {
  padding-top: 0.938rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.938rem;
}

#search_collapse { padding-top: 1.563rem;}

#search_collapse.show {
  padding-bottom: 2.813rem;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .title_home {
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.13;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 0.9375rem;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 3.75rem);

}

.bloc_advanced_search .title_home::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.875rem;
  height: 0.375rem;
  content: "";
  background: #ff7900;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .form-input {
  margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .form-input label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2.813rem;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .form-input .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 1.375rem;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: text;
  color: #808080;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.625rem;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  transition: border-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 2.813rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;

}

.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input {
  height: 2.813rem;
}
.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input:focus,
.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input:valid {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input:focus + .placeholder,
.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input:valid + .placeholder {
  top: 0;
  cursor: inherit;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #808080;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .btn-bottom {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .rectangle {
  width: 3.125rem;
  height: 3.125rem;;
  padding: 1.188rem 1rem;
  background-color: #ff7900;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.938rem;
  top: 0;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .rectangle::after {
  content: "\e93f";
  font-family: icon-orange, sans-serif;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: -0.313rem;
}

.bloc_advanced_search .rectangle.disabled {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #000;
}

.bloc_advanced_search.interne .rectangle {
  top: -0.938rem;
}

.bloc_advanced_search.interne .rectangle[aria-expanded=false]::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.bloc_advanced_search .reset_input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.625rem;
  bottom: -0.188rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

My problem is in particular in **IPAD mode** ,

When changing my focus from an input to another , the IOS Keyboard seems to be closed and reopened betwen an input to another , that results me to double click each time on every input to get it fosused (and in parallel a close/open keyboard each time

My purpose , is to , **to keep the keyboard appearing when flying from an input to another** , and with a simple one ckick , setting focus on desired input and beeing able to write.

Of course when click outside the form or inputs zone , the keyboard should diseppear .

**Is there any simple way to do it properly ??**

Answer (score 0):

i correct it
by changing z-index , and making the input in front of the placeholder

Furthemore i set the background of input as transparent to make the plaeholder visible also

```
.bloc_advanced_search .form-input input {
  background: transparent; /* <- THIS  */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.625rem;
  z-index: 3;  /* <- THIS  */
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  transition: border-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 2.813rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;

}
```